# JQuery File Upload sends each file in individual Post Request?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

My problem is simple and complex same time:

Im tryin to upload files using jQuery fileUpload library with spring mvc controller as server side, but my files are being uploaded by one request each. What i want is posting them ALL in ONE request.

I have tried **singleFileUploads: false** option but its not working, if i pass 4 files to upload, the method responsible for handling the post is called 4 times.

Im using this form to post files:

```
<div class="upload-file-div">
    <b>Choose csv files to load</b> <input id="csvUpload" type="file"
    name="files[] "data-url="adminpanel/uploadCsv" multiple />
</div>
<div id="dropzoneCsv">Or drop files here</div>

<div id="progressCsv">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery method to upload files:

```
$('#csvUpload').fileupload(
                {
                    singleFileUploads: false,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    done : function(e, data) {
                        $("tr:has(td)").remove();
                        $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {

                            $("#uploaded-csv").append(
                                    $('<tr/>').append(
                                            $('<td/>').text(file.fileName))
                                            .append(
                                                    $('<td/>').text(
                                                            file.fileSize))
                                            .append(
                                                    $('<td/>').text(
                                                            file.fileType))
                                            .append(
                                                    $('<td/>').text(
                                                            file.existsOnServer))
                                            .append($('<td/>')));
                        });
                    },

                    progressall : function(e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100,
                                10);
                        $('#progressCsv .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                    },

                    dropZone : $('#dropzoneCsv')
                });
```

And handler method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminpanel/uploadCsv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<FileMeta> uploadCsv(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // 1. build an iterator
        Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile mpf = null;
        List<FileMeta> csvFiles = new ArrayList<FileMeta>();
        // 2. get each file
        while (itr.hasNext()) {

            // 2.1 get next MultipartFile
            mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
            System.out.println(mpf.getOriginalFilename() + " uploaded! ");

            // 2.3 create new fileMeta
            FileMeta fileMeta = new FileMeta();
            fileMeta.setFileName(mpf.getOriginalFilename());
            fileMeta.setFileSize(mpf.getSize() / 1024 + " Kb");
            fileMeta.setFileType(mpf.getContentType());

            try {
                File dir = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                        .getResource("").getPath()+"CSV");
                if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
                File newCSV = new File(dir+"\\"+ mpf.getOriginalFilename());
                if(!newCSV.exists())
                {
                    mpf.transferTo(newCSV);
                    fileMeta.setExistsOnServer(false);
                }
                else fileMeta.setExistsOnServer(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // 2.4 add to files
            csvFiles.add(fileMeta);
        }

        return csvFiles;
    }
```

I would really need an assistance here :( Files should be loaded in one request, thats why im doing the iterator, but its just not working.

ps. Sorry for my terrible english :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to try [Programmatic file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload) instead. The `send` method will ensure only one request is issued.

Basically keep a `filelist` variable, update it everytime `fileuploadadd` callback happens, then use this `filelist` for the `send` method.

For example:

```
$document.ready(function(){
    var filelist = [];
    $('#form').fileupload({
    ... // your fileupload options
    }).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++){
            filelist.push(data.files[i])
        }
    })

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#form').fileupload('send', {files:filelist});
    })

})
```

It is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807361/uploading-multiple-files-asynchronously-by-blueimp-jquery-fileupload).

The reason I found it useful is even if you set `singleFileUploads` to `false`, if you do multiple individual selections, they will still be sent with individual requests each, as the author said himself in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2549)

Comment: I suppose #button is referring to the button with that id, so if we had a submit button in the form... Should we remove the <form> tag and use the #button or there is a way for attaching  the same action to the submit action in the form? Which is the right one?

Comment: @madtyn I went with the #button approach (i.e no <form> tag). Personally I seldom use the form tag with a submit button as it doesn't play well with many javascript calls.