# Uploading multiple files asynchronously by blueimp jquery-fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I'm using jQuery File Upload library (http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), and I've been stuck figuring out how to use the library satisfying the following conditions.

- The page has multiple file input fields surrounded by a form tag.
- Users can attach multiple files to each input field
- All files are sent to a server when the button is clicked, not when files are attached to the input fields.
- Upload is done asynchronously
- Say the page has 3 input fields with their name attributes being "file1[]", "file2[]" and "file3[]", the request payload should be like {file1: [ array of files on file1[] ], file2: [ array of files on file2[] ], ...}

Here's jsFiddle, it's behaving weird so far in that it sends post request twice and the first one is cancelled.

## Updates

Now thanks to @CBroe 's comment, the issue that request is sent twice is fixed. However the keys of request parameter is not correctly set.
Here's updated jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BAQtG/27/

---

The core part of js code looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filesList = []
    var elem = $("form")
    file_upload = elem.fileupload({
        formData:{extra:1},
        autoUpload: false,
        fileInput: $("input:file"),
    }).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data){
        filesList.push(data.files[0])
    });

    $("button").click(function(){
        file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList} )
    })

})
```

Anybody have idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BAQtG/29/

And js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filesList = [],
        paramNames = [],
        elem = $("form");
    file_upload = elem.fileupload({
        formData:{extra:1},
        autoUpload: false,
        fileInput: $("input:file"),
    }).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data){
        filesList.push(data.files[0]);
        paramNames.push(e.delegatedEvent.target.name);
    });

    $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
    })
})
```

Comment: The jsfiddle code doesn't actually attach the files themselves to the POST. (it's application/x-www-form-encoded, not mulitpart)  

Any suggestions on what is missing from the example?

Answer (score 1):

The first POST request triggered by your script gets canceled, because the button **submits** the form (causing the second POST request).

Use `type="button"` on the `button` if you *don’t* want it to have submit functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this was part of the issue! Now the problem left is how to send files with multiple keys using the library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either add a `return false;`, as shown below:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList} )
    return false;
})
```

or specify the `type="button"` attribute:

```
<button type="button">send by fileupload send api</button>
```

In order to set the `formData`, use the following:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    file_upload.fileupload('send', {
        files: filesList,
        formData: {
            json: JSON.encode({
                extra: 1
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Specifically for *JSFiddle*, if you want to get the `extra` value in the response, you have to encode it and assign it to a property named `json`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BAQtG/30/)'s a working example.

Comment: Thank you for this. As mentioned above, the keys of request parameter are not still set correctly.