# How to use BlueImp jquery-file-upload to pass parameters using send option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I know there are other question *like* this around, but the solutions are not working for me. Can someone help me figure out how pass parameters using a POST request with the jquery-file-upload library, specifically when the `send` option is being used:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: [file]} )
.success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Success...");
});
```

I've tried the following:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {
    files: [file], 
    formData: {'fileType': fileType}
})
```

and also:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({formData: {'fileType': fileType} });
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: [file]})
```

and I've tried putting `formData` in the format of `formData: [{name:'fileType', value:fileType}]`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem a few minutes ago. You should use :

```
file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
```

I found it here: [Uploading multiple files asynchronously by blueimp jquery-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807361/uploading-multiple-files-asynchronously-by-blueimp-jquery-fileupload)

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful, but it still doesn't work for me. paramNames seems to be just an array containing the param names, what about the values?

Comment: I don't have anything better than [How-to-submit-additional-form-data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data). paramNames helped me with wrong field names when multiple files are send in single request.

Comment: I've read through it already and unfortunately it didn't help me. Thanks anyway