# I want to Upload Multiple Files whatever may be the format

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using [BlueImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to **Upload Multiple Files** at a time.

Now i have only one issue with this component that before writing on server it stores a temporary local copy on Server in temporary folder and after clicking on "UPLOAD" button it finally uploads it where i want to , but i cannot give access to this component to write anything temporarily in any folder on Server.

I don't have any option for this component as this suites my requirement.

I basically want a component in Jquery which can upload my files of any format from Client side to Server without storing any local copy on my Server.
and if i can't get any such component then i want help in finding how can i stop [BlueImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) from writing on my Server as temporary copy

Comment: might be help you ,Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807361/uploading-multiple-files-asynchronously-by-blueimp-jquery-fileupload

Comment: I saw your link @ParthAkbari but that issue is for that BlueImp sending same request twice and what i want is that it should not write in temporary folder.Thanks

Comment: Any help ?? by anyone??