# How to add files dynamically in input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery-File-Upload plugin for file upload. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

My question is how to add a array of files to input `files[]` dynamically on click using `JQuery`?

Below is the code, that I am trying but I think something went wrong.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/css/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-JavaScript-Templates/3.11.0/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.19.0/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/javascript-canvas-to-blob/3.14.0/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
  <form id="fileupload" action="https://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files on click</span>
        </span>
        
        
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button hide">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
      </div>
      <!-- The global progress state -->
      <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
        <!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- The extended global progress state -->
        <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="files"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>




<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td style="width:20px !important;">
      <span href="{%=file.url%}" class="image_pop" style="cursor:pointer"><span class="preview hid"></span></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100px !important;vertical-align: middle;">
      <div style="max-width:250px;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis">
        <span class="name" title="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100px !important;vertical-align: middle;">
      <span class="size">Processing...</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                Start
                </button> {% } %} {% if (!i) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                Cancel
                </button> {% } %}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-download fade">
    <td style="width:20px !important;">
      <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
      <td style="width:100px !important;vertical-align: middle;">
        <div style="max-width:250px;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis">
          <span class="name" title="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</span>
        </div>
        <td style="width:100px !important;vertical-align: middle;">
          <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
          <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}" {% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {% } %}>
          Delete
                </button>
          <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle"> {% } else { %}
          <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          Cancel
                </button> {% } %}
        </td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>


<script>
$('.fileinput-button').on('click', function () {
  
  var $json = ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/1124092/pexels-photo-1124092.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=abstract-art-background-1124092.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1145357/pexels-photo-1145357.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=blue-sky-clouds-countryside-1145357.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/861233/pexels-photo-861233.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=asphalt-car-close-up-861233.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1174183/pexels-photo-1174183.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=4k-wallpaper-conifers-environment-1174183.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1167110/pexels-photo-1167110.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-animal-breed-1167110.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/457446/pexels-photo-457446.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=clouds-fashion-landscape-457446.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170594/pexels-photo-1170594.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=abstract-art-blue-sky-1170594.jpg&fm=jpg",
 "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1006293/pexels-photo-1006293.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=contemporary-desk-eyeglasses-1006293.jpg&fm=jpg"];

  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    dataType: 'json',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
  }).fileupload('add', {
     files: $json
  });
  
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files asynchronously by blueimp jquery-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807361/uploading-multiple-files-asynchronously-by-blueimp-jquery-fileupload)

Comment: Not worked @Alex

Comment: Did you get an error? Did anything happen? Did you simply copy & paste the code or have you implemented it into your solution?